# Water loop with a drop output?

Tags: water-resources, flow-control

Hello everyone this project is for my aquarium.

I have a big bucket beside it on the floor and I was planning on using it for the water changes. Will be a neocaridina shrimp breeding aquarium so my goal is to maintain water parameters stable with very slowly changing between water changes.

So the main goal is to pour the new water into the bucket and slowly geting it released to the aquarium at a constant and even dripping rate so water never overflows on either side as well. Basicly the water will be forever flowing from one to the other.

Moving the water from aquarium to bucket is easy thanks to gravity but uphill.... how can I do it with a dripping system at the end at 2+ meters high? I guessed If I just use a tiny water pump with a airline tube leading into the aquarium could work but water pressure worries me caused by the dripping output...

What other materials must be used? Is this idea viable or just a waste of time?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you definitely can do that.

There are small filler pumps that will automatically kick into power when the water falls below the present level and the floater activates the pump.

So you can have the discharge drip continuously but the infill intermittently, automatically. And by putting a call control valve on the drain path, you control the whole circulation.

Answer (score 1):

Drip irrigation parts cost about five cents a piece. They come in fractional gallons per hour at 25 psi. So pump the water into the tank from the bucket via a drip head, and use a simple float valve to regulate the outflow. First thought is a carb float. Toilet float might work as well.

Comment: Thank you il try google thise but could you two dumb it down a little please? If you get the time.